# Loading a time series into R

Tags: r, time-series

i would like to load the following data structure as a time series into R:

```
Date        06:00   07:00   .... 22:00
01.11.2011  1       4       .... 42
02.11.2011  6       2       .... 21
```

...

is this loadable with R ? Do i need to transform my data ? 
can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create some data:

```
Lines <- "Date        06:00   07:00   08:00
01.11.2011  1       4       42
02.11.2011  6       2       21"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Now create zoo object `z` using `chron` date/times:

```
library(zoo)
library(chron)

tt <- as.chron(outer(DF[[1]], names(DF)[-1], paste), format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
z <- zoo(c(as.matrix(DF[-1])), tt)
```

(Replacing `as.chron` with `as.POSIXct` would give POSIXct date/times.)